# Proper way of building Gtk3 applications in Python

Tags: python, gtk3

I have just started learning about creating GUI apps in Python. I decided to use Gtk version 3.
According to the (official?) tutorial on http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/ the proper way of building a hello world application is:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(200, 100)
        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

MyWindow()
Gtk.main()
```

In other tutorial (http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk3-python-hello-world.html) I found completly different aproach which is:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

class HelloWorldApp(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self, application_id="apps.test.helloworld",
                                 flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE)
        self.connect("activate", self.on_activate)

    def on_activate(self, data=None):
        window = Gtk.Window(type=Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Gtk3 Python Example")
        window.set_border_width(24)
        label = Gtk.Label("Hello World!")
        window.add(label)
        window.show_all()
        self.add_window(window)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.run(None)
```

Could someone experienced in this category tell me in what way should I write Gtk 3 apps in python these days? I'm already familiar with writing GUIs (spent few months in Java's Swing) so you can go on with terms like events, callbacks and so on..

Answer (score 15):

Choosing to write your new program with a GtkApplication or just a GtkWindow depends on the functionality you require, and to some extent the intended audience.

For most cases, especially when you are still learning the toolkit, I would tend to agree with valmynd that GtkApplication is unnecessarily complicated.  GtkApplication provides a lot of extra functionality that you probably don't want or need in smaller applications.

For larger, more complete applications I agree with Dragnucs, the second approach is superior and can provide better integration into the desktop environment.  From [*GNOME Goal: Port to GtkApplication*](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/GnomeGoals/PortToGtkApplication) (see also the [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) docs):

> Porting your application to use GtkApplication has quite nice benefits:
>   GtkApplication handles GTK+ initialization, application uniqueness, session management, provides some basic scriptability and desktop shell integration by exporting actions and menus and manages a list of toplevel windows whose life-cycle is automatically tied to the life-cycle of your application.

However I disagree with Dragnucs about why the GtkWindow approach is introduced in the tutorial.  I tend to think simple examples with very little boilerplate are more appropriate for a tutorials *Getting Started* section (but, I do think that the read-the-docs tutorial needs to be updated to include at least some mention of GtkApplication).

In applications I've written I tend to either subclass both GtkApplication and GtkWindow or for single window *quick-and-nasty* applications just subclass GtkWindow.  Your decision will depend on your applications needs.

**Technical difference:** There is also an important technical difference between how the two examples are implemented.  The example with just a GtkWindow creates a new Gtk main loop for each instance of the program.  The example with GtkApplication creates a single main loop attached to the first instance and each subsequent call to `run(None)` will request that the original instance create a new window (the new instance will then exit).  Try opening up two terminals and running your application in each window, notice that one terminal will wait until all the windows have closed before becoming sensitive again.  You can change this behaviour by using `G_APPLICATION_NON_UNIQUE` instead of `G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE`.

Answer (score 6):

The second code example looks unnecessary complicated to me, the first looks perfectly fine. The author of that second tutorial has put a link to another, even more simple example ([Source](http://www.micahcarrick.com/hello-world-in-python-gtk3.html)):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.connect("destroy", lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())
window.add(Gtk.Label("Hello World!"))
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

There is nothing wrong with either approaches. You can use all the default widgets, not subclassing anything, like in the example above. Or you can subclass certain widgets, mainly as a way to give your code a nice structure and having re-usable custom/modified widgets in the end. That is all up to you.

The same applies to Qt and many other GUI frameworks, btw.

Comment: I am a bit late here but for anyone that find this, I think the biggest difference has to do with if you are making an app with more than 1 window, `Gtk.Window` seems to open a new window each time you call one which means you have multiple windows open for the same app but with `Gtk.Application` you can open different programs in the same window. There might be a way to do it with `Window` but I haven't seen it. With Application you just call `ApplicationWindow`.

Answer (score 6):

The second approach is better. It makes the application more integrated into the desktop and informs more about what it does or is meant to do. It also provides you with more tools to use with your application.

I think the first approach is just not up to date or something. The second one is really the preferred way.

You can see that the application [Gnome-music](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-music/) is actually using the [second approach](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-music/blob/master/gnomemusic/application.py) with Gtk.Application usage. All the official Gnome apps are using Gtk.Application, and all Gtk application should be using it too.